Python selenium job works different on Jenkins slave on windows running under powershell commandline vs running under winsw/task scheduler
I have a python selenium script using chromedriver.exe in headless mode to perform some rota tasks on ibm esa web application, python selenium script when executed from powershell command line works fine as expected, but when running through jenkins on slave which is managed by winsw/task scheduler it is skipping selenium steps. In another case, jenkins job executing the selenium python script is running fine on jenkins slave when starting agent.jar from powershell command line (PS> Java.exe -jar agent.jar -jlnp  secret).
Chrome driver log shows no errors and shows same events for both the cases
Slave running on windows server 2016, we are using cloudbees jenkins latest, running the pipeline job on windows slave
Running jenkins slave directly from powershell command line, the python selenium job when triggered from master when jenkins slave started from powershell cli is working as expected. But the same is not working when running the slave under task scheduler / winsw
I have tried to run service as local system account with "allow access to desktop" option & dedicated account as well but no luck

Can you elaborate in your question how your slave on windows server 2016 is connected to the jenkins master? Are launching the agent from the master or the you are first running from CLI from node that connects to the master.
Also please share how does your node service configuration xml looks like.

Our setup is cloudbees jenkins, jenkins slave is running using jnlp command
